# C# - Convert Time From String

Tags: c#, int

Heyo, I want to know how can I do something so Its converts for example [1m] to 60 seconds.
Also like 30s or 2h.

Any help will be Appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: what did you try

Comment: @Sajeetharan Well, I get the string and then I do if time.Contains("m")

Comment: And I don't know what to do now. I think something with int but I don't know what

Comment: i am not clear what you need to do

Comment: I have method so the method getting strings like 1m , 1h and etc...

Comment: Do you know about the `Substring` method of the string class?  If the time designator is always 1 character, parse the rest of the string as an integer.  Use the time designator to figure out what conversion factor to use.

Comment: @Plugin4U Edit your question and update with your string which you try to convert into time

Answer (score -1):

String value = "Thu Mar 02 1995 21:31:00,2245107";

```
String[] token = value.Split(',');

String[] datetime = token[0].Split(' ');

String timeText = datetime[4]; // The String array contans 21:31:00

DateTime time = Convert.ToDateTime(timeText); // Converts only the time

Console.WriteLine(time.ToString("HH:mm:ss"));
```

Comment: How I get the time from 1m??

Comment: @HARSHPATEL op expectation is different ;)